# Instalar .Net Core SDK e RunTime pelo terminal do Windows?

Tags: windows, terminal, asp.net-core

Preciso instalar tanto o Runtime quanto a SDK do .Net Core na máquina da faculdade, no entanto, único lugar em que consigo colocar um proxy de acesso geral é no Terminal, então gostaria de saber se tem como instalar esses dos componentes via terminal do windows?

ps: Não consigo instalar nada por ser necessário privilégios de administrador para isso.

Comment: O q vc chama de terminal?

Comment: E se ao invés de tentar usar o terminal, você levar o .exe do .NET Core em um pendrive e depois instalar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usando chocolatey
Link:https://chocolatey.org/

pode fazer isso

```
choco install dotnetcore-runtime
```

Link:https://chocolatey.org/packages/dotnetcore-runtime